# Why does Azure B2C return idp_access_token which is not a jwt?

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup Azure B2C to return a claim called idp_access_token and according to this Microsoft documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview

it should be a valid JWT. However it is not a valid JWT.

Why is that?

```json
"exp": 1588112929,
"nbf": 1588109329,
"ver": "1.0",
"iss": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com/903e0c59-0e1d-4769-8a57-0caba1f561da/v2.0/",
"sub": "f11eaa2e-0bad-400a-864f-57f9daa70720",
"aud": "8ab24fa8-a5f2-4f7d-a1ad-31f21d7fb627",
"nonce": "defaultNonce",
"iat": 1588109329,
"auth_time": 1588109329,
"idp_access_token": "PAQABAAAAAAAm-06blBE1TpVMil8KPQ41KrxufgbIw-NxMJGBuFrfjebtTsSNCwe_5MK208-HdCSx2GkqvSr7LV7ZZiKD9p4z7Zl-NawHeA4DJiPxlnmZB43ObtstvlmwyDoVzTFxSjdOkGvCv5_7A5JuGqct7VBbp1US7HmC2YeS9xVO6HlNiYWlNu90HQwk8A05fnzYwfhcshWQ5JvblgtbkwP6dlK4r_PM9erowtW0LuWkEeucdbU_DfnnM75nFbL4Bo4o_-j5nReC7wBpx_dhVC5gDItLuvuQUruju-3ANDSNsSzlNrp6RCv1HOZtMohVbRB6GYDYS0222u7_hf4by-bQca2SIxWvSZ1UKCPUmnQ0Ji4lYCrkCPlKTOPaUaf1D6yZHbWJtqYkOBY-8uuf7961GyDceW_szZhX80AUkEmK5t9yMd7jB38nV5lvHI13roMzr8N-jWdPSOcLCLxSWIvNG7Inp_5wGM2yYSCTjWUnCTMR8-UkXCETUIU16bw2FkTJc1K_eZhAYw2UyQIzYejd-9gQhZrHyTE0ogApg-Qm4bYnW0XCHGe4MZjDKNuVu49OEGTOxUrn7g0Zh9dn6k6FNma7O02ERUItq2bmpYSyqsRxIase4-9tn_zEhoV-lT1mdIHCDXPLwsH...some more comes here
 ...
```

More background information:

- I'm using "Sign up and sign in v2 (Preview)" user flow
- As identity provider of the flow I have selected an Open ID Connect IDP configured to use the Azure AD of the same Azure subscription in which the Azure AD B2C resided.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is the AAD blob used to hit the user info endpoint. You get this as an access token if you don’t specify a resource (v1 AAD endpoint), or scope (v2 endpoint) as part of the auth request.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get valid "idp_access_token", you have to set "v2.0" in metaurl of OpenId Identity Provider Configurations.

As you can not edit metaurl for previous identity provider, create new one with "v2.0" in metaurl.

Your metaurl will be look like this,

https://login.microsoftonline.com/**tenant-name**.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Please replace **"tenant-name"** with your tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this functionality of retrieving external IDP (identity provider) access_token would be extremely useful to relying parties(RP), if they (RP) want to then talk directly to the (external) IDP by providing this ( idp_access_token) token a bearer to do some operations.

Several Identity Brokers provide this feature; for example:

1. Keycloak : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#retrieving-external-idp-tokens
2. Auth0 - https://auth0.com/docs/connections/calling-an-external-idp-api

I have some experience working with Keycloak and some of the Relying Parties I work with do use this feature in Keycloak -- to pull in some additional information about the authenticated user.

Well, there are some settings and configurations and permissions need to be done both at the IDP broker side (first leg) and at the second leg as well. I guess, that is beyond the scope of the question asked.